# Leaflet Cluster changes all my customs marker icons

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have 4 custom marker icons which are displayed on the map based on some conditons set in the code. without the leaflet cluster, they are all showing but when i add the leaflet cluster, it automatically changes all the different customs icons to one.

```
<div id="map-view" style="z-index: 1; height: 550px; width: 100%"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
 let locations = [{ "network_operator": "MTN",
                        "latitude":6.50895,
                        "longitude":3.37028
                   },{ "network_operator": "GLO",            
                       "latitude":6.590604,  
                        "longitude":3.541904
                    }];
        const authorizedUser = {
            user1: ['MTN', 'Operator'],
            user2: ['GLO', 'Operator'],
            user3: ['9MOBILE','Operator'],
            user4: ['AIRTEL','Operator'],
            staff: ['ZYSOD','Staff']
        };

            const operatorStaffColor = {
                'MTN': '/static/img/marker-icon-mtn.png', //MTN
                'GLO': '/static/img/marker-icon-glo.png', //glo
                '9MOBILE': '/static/img/marker-icon-9mobile.png',
                'AIRTEL': '/static/img/marker-icon-airtel.png' //airtel
            }
    var enteredURL = window.location.pathname;
    var user = enteredURL.slice(4, (enteredURL.length)+1); // get the actual value after slicing 
    // the user variable is gotten from the URL which is later used in the script
var operatorIcon = new L.Icon({ 
                iconUrl: '', 
                shadowUrl: '/static/img/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                labelAnchor: [6, 0],
                shadowSize: [41, 41]
              });
    let mymap = L.map("map-view", {
                                        doubleClickZoom:!1,
                                        closePopupOnClick:!1            
                                    }).setView([9.367231, 7.765842], 6); 
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { 
                                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' 
                                    }).addTo(mymap); 
                                    var markers = new L.markerClusterGroup({ disableClusteringAtZoom: 14 ,spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, showCoverageOnHover: false, zoomToBoundsOnClick: false, animate:false});
     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if(authorizedUser[user][1] ==='Operator'){
    operatorIcon.options.iconUrl=operatorStaffColor[locations[i].network_operator]}
else{
        operatorIcon.options.iconUrl=operatorStaffColor[locations[i].network_operator];
        }
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([locations[i].latitude,locations[i].longitude], {icon: operatorIcon}).bindPopup(status, {
                                                autoClose: !1, 
                                                closeButton: !1, 
                                                maxWidth: 560
                                                    }));
        }                
                                        mymap.addLayer(markers);
        markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
                                            console.log('click');
                                            a.layer.spiderfy();
                                        });
```

Comment: Where are you using Network type?  You are never using operatorStaffColor.  Shouldn't you assign the color to operatorIcon right before markers.addLayer?

Comment: @zakariah1 I have updated the codes. Everything is working except that the cluster changes all the markers to the last assigned marker in the `for loop`

Comment: I think that this authorizedUser[user][1] ==='Operator' is never true, but the way the code is and your question is it does not matter.  Did you mean authorizedUser[:user1]?  Can you try not using markers and then try the following? L.marker([locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude], { icon: operatorIcon }).bindPopup(status, {
    autoClose: !1,
    closeButton: !1,
    maxWidth: 560
}).addTo(mymap);

Comment: @zakariah1 that condition works but that is not my problem. the main issue is that leaflet cluster convert all the different marker icons into just one (this last assigned icons in the for loop). this makes it difficult to differentiate markers

Comment: Thank you i have discovered the problem